# Find distinct dataSets in a list

Tags: c#

I have a structure for example:

```
struct DataSet
{ 
   string a, 
   string b , 
   string c, 
   string d
}
```

And I have a list of Datasets, for example: `List<DataSet> DataSets = new List<DataSet>();`

I want to find distinct DataSets in a list ignoring string `c`.

E.g

If I have two DataSets in a list where DataSet1 has (a=1, b=2, **c=3,** d=4) and DataSet2 has (a=1, b= 2, **c= 13,** d= 4)

As My result I should get only one DataSet value ignoring whatever c holds. So my result would be DataSet1(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) OR DatsSet2(a=1, b=2, c=13, d= 4) but not both.

Any Ideas?

Comment: @GrantWinney If you're referring to the fact that there was no generic argument; it was there, but he didn't code escape it when posting it to SO.  If you're referring to him not showing how it's populated, that doesn't really matter...

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks for your reply. The code belongs to by company hence I cannot post it here.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `GroupBy` and group on the three columns you care about:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(data => new{data.a, data.b, data.d})
    .Select(group => group.First())//just choose one from the group
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I will try it and post my results ASAP.